# R Summary function shows null and integer

Tags: r, function, summary

I have data with Gender and protein expression and I need to find the relationship between them . I tried to get the summary of each first, however the summary function in R shows me NULL and integer. I tried multiple variations but they don't work for me. Please help!

This is the table how it looks like :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzcSC.png)

And this is what it shows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DokD.png)

Comment: It looks to me as if your attempt to read the text file has failed. What do you get from `print(GTEX)`? And please help yourself by helping us to help you by providing a *minimal reproducible example*. Welcome to SO.

Comment: No, it reads the file as other functions working but not the summary one. From print(GTEX) it shows the data frame

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Please don't upload code, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).